# Running a Function on Click Returns Stale State Values React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am refactoring a class component into a functional component with React Hooks in an app that runs a specific function on click. The function references state values, but the state values in the function are stale, and it causes the app to crash.

I've seen similar questions on StackOverflow, but most of the onClick functions do only one thing, so their use of useRef or useCallback seem much easier to implement. How can I ensure that the checkAnswer function is using updated state values?

```
 const Find = props => {
  const [currentCountry, setCurrentCountry] = useState(null)
  const [guesses, setGuesses] = useState(null)
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])
```

**EDIT**

The setCurrentCountry hook is called in the takeTurn function, which runs at the start of the game.

```
  const takeTurn = () => {
            !props.isStarted && props.startGame();
            let country = getRandomCountry();
            console.log(country)
            setGuesses(prevGuess => prevGuess + 1)
            setCurrentCountry(country)
            console.log('setting currentCountry')
            getAnswers(country)
            let nodes = [...(document.getElementsByClassName("gameCountry"))];
            nodes.forEach( node => {
              node.removeAttribute("style")
            })
            if(questions && questions.length === 10){
                console.log('opening modal')
                props.handleOpen();
                // alert("Congrats! You've reached the end of the game. You answered " + props.correct + " questions correctly and " + props.incorrect + " incorrectly.\n Thanks for playing");
                console.log('ending game')
                props.gameOver && endGame();

            }


  const getAnswers = (currentCountry) => {
      console.log(currentCountry)
        let answerQuestions;
        if(questions){
          answerQuestions = [...questions]
        }
        let question = {};
        question['country'] = currentCountry;
        question['correct'] = null;
        let answers = [];
        currentCountry && console.log(currentCountry.name);
        console.log(currentCountry)
        currentCountry && answers.push({
            name: currentCountry.name.split(';')[0],
            correct: 2
        });
        console.log(answers)
        answerQuestions.push(question);
        setQuestions(answerQuestions)
    }
  const checkAnswer = (e, country) => {
        let checkquestions = questions;
        let question = checkquestions.find(question => question.country === currentCountry);
        let checkguesses = guesses;
        console.log(e)
        console.log(country)
        console.log(currentCountry)
        if(!props.isStarted){
          return
        }
        if((country === currentCountry.name || country === currentCountry.name) || guesses === 4){
            props.updateScore(3-guesses);
            console.log(question);
            if(guesses === 1){
                question['correct'] = true;
            }
            checkguesses = null;
            setTimeout(() => takeTurn(), 300);   
        } else {
            question['correct'] = false;
            checkguesses ++
            if(guesses === 3){
              getCountryInfo(e, currentCountry.name);
            }
        }
        setGuesses(checkguesses)
        props.handlePoints(questions);
    }
```

The rendered data with the onClick:

```
          <Geographies  geography={data}>
            {(geos, proj) =>
              geos.map((geo, i) =>
              <Geography
                data-idkey={i}
                onClick={((e) => checkAnswer(e, geo.properties.NAME_LONG))}
                key={i}
                geography={geo}
                projection={proj}
                className="gameCountry"       
              />
            )
            }
          </ Geographies>
          </ZoomableGroup>
```

The app stalls because the state values for currentCountry are still being read as null.

Comment: I think we need more code. Can you post the entire component? Where is `setCurrentCountry` being called?

Comment: @jered I added more of the pertinent code to the snippet. SetCurrentCount is being called in the takeTurn function that runs on start and after every question is answered.

Comment: so you say inside `checkAnswer()` `currentCountry` is always `null`, right?

Comment: @skyboyer yes that's correct. I console logged the currentCountry outside of the function, and it returns the updated value.